# SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python

This is an easy problem for someone experienced in python. I am not and simply need to use this little piece of code and probably never use it again anywhere else thus I am asking the stackoverflow gods for their mercy. I am attempting to run from terminal. cd into desktop and run the ourfleet.py.rtf. My error is the dreaded: File "ourfleet.py.rtf", line 1
    {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1347\cocoasubrtf570
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

ultimate first time python user as well as last time python user just need this to work. Thumbs up to the best answer. I have newest python version installed & running a macbook.

```
import serial
import time
import requests
import json

firebase_url = 'https://ourfleet.firebaseio.com'

#Connect to Serial Port for communication
ser = serial.Serial(‘dev/tty.wchusbserial410’, 4800, timeout=0)

#Setup a loop to send GPS values at fixed intervals
#in seconds
fixed_interval = 10

while 1:
 try:
 #gps value obtained from Arduino + LM35 Temp Sensor
 gps_c = ser.readline()
 #current time and date
 time_hhmmss = time.strftime(&quot;%H:%M:%S&quot;)
 date_mmddyyyy = time.strftime(&quot;%d/%m/%Y&quot;)

 #current location name
 gps_location = &quot;Doug C.&quot;

 print “gps_c + ',' + time_hhmmss + ',' + date_mmddyyyy + ',' + gps_location”

 #insert record

 data = {'date':date_mmddyyyy,'time':time_hhmmss,'value’:gps_c}

 result = requests.post(firebase_url + &quot;/&quot; + gps_location + &quot;/gps.json&quot;, data=json.dumps(data))

 #insert record
 print “&quot;Record inserted. Result Code = &quot; + str(result.status_code) + &quot;,&quot; +   result.text”
 time.sleep(fixed_interval)
 except IOError:
 print('Error! Something went wrong.')
 time.sleep(fixed_interval)
```

Comment: are you really using `”` and `’`?

Comment: Wait - you've saved your file as an RTF? "ourfleet.py.rtf"?

Answer (score 0):

You've saved your script as a Rich Text Format document.  Don't do that.  Save it as plain text.

While you're at it, don't use [smart quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_quotes) since Python doesn't understand them.

Comment: Thanks to all for the input I have modified my code and it seems to be running fine now . I have some other errors coming up so I've started a new thread elsewhere for that. What seems to have happened is when I saved the original code as .rtf and then converted to .py it saved a bunch of new line characters and some meta data at the top of the code specifying things like font color etc; I went through and edited out this info as well and eliminated quotes and all is well.